# Generate date/ time stamp when data is entered/ changed

Tags: excel, vba, datetime, excel-formula

I have a register which can be used to track the current status of document completion.
I want a way to automatically put a date/ time stamp dependant on the status entered into a column
For example, when a document is started the status column (Column Q) is entered with 0%, and the date of that should go into the next column (Column R).
At 25%, the status column updated to 25%, and (Column S), should be updated with the date
At 50%, the status column updated to 50%, and (Column T), should be updated with the date
At 75%, the status column updated to 75%, and (Column U), should be updated with the date
At 100%, the status column updated to 100%, and (Column V), should be updated with the date
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DLVB.png)
Throughout all of this, the previous columns should keep their date

At one point I was able to get this working with a formula, in each column, but this working intermittently and only on some devices.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(E1453),"", IF(R1453="",NOW(),R1453))
=IF(Q1453>=0.25, IF(S1453="",NOW(),S1453), "")
=IF(Q1453>=0.5, IF(T1453="",NOW(),T1453), "")
=IF(Q1453>=0.75, IF(U1453="",NOW(),U1453), "")
=IF(Q1453>=1, IF(V1453="",NOW(),V1453), "")
```

Is there a way to get this working, either through fixing the formulas or via a macro?
It needs to be from Row 1453 through to row 3000

Comment: It will only work with VBA, since you want to keep the timestamp static. `Now()` is volatile and will always update to the current time. For help with vba, see the `Worksheet_Change` event.